# What is the correct way of normalizing data in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I generate input data for my model at different temperatures. At each temperature I generate 1000 samples and in each sample I have 16 features. So the shape of array is (1000,16) at each temperature. I want to normalize data between 0 and 1. But I am really confused that what is the strategy of normalization in machine learning language? Should I normalize feature of each single sample such that each sample is like [0,.....1] or should I normalize along column axis. Secondly I also want to know that should I perform this normalization separately for each temperature?

Comment: You normalize each variable (column) separately.

Comment: You mean feature of every single sample?

Comment: You normalize each variable (feature) separately, for all samples.

Comment: Sorry may be I'm misunderstanding your statement.In my question I have 16 features in each sample. So after normalization I will get [0......1].length of this vector is 16.Is this what you want to convey?

Comment: Normalize the whole feature (with all the samples), that is extract every 1000 length vector (total of 16), apply normalization to each such vector.

Comment: But why we normalize 1000 length vector instead of features of single sample(16-length). In machine learning we assume that features lie on the different scale and we want to shift then on the same scale. According to this statement we should normalize 16 features of a single sample. And repeat this procedure for every sample

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize each column separately. After normalization each feature should have a maximum value at 1 and a minimum at 0.